# Read value from file, after 12 times ","

Tags: c#, count, sum, readlines

i have file, where i have separated values via "," - but it's not .csv extension.
I'm trying to get in C# sum from each row, which start from 0.

To this sum, should be taken always value after 12th of ","

```
0,P2CZ,1,0,400,400,802,802,18,18,1299,,5,248721,2487221,2
1,1,2487221,1,1_EG_3ST2_1/22,,0,460,18,0
0,,2,0,400,400,982,982,18,18,13999,,9,2321,248731,24878/121,24872021,,,,,,
1,1,2482021,1,1_EG_9_ST2_1/22,,0,460,18,0
1,3,2487821,1,1_EG_U9_ST2_1/22,,0,1042,18,0
1,4,248781,1,1_EG_U9_ST2_1/22,,0,1042,18,0
0,,3,0,2000,2000,80,80,18,18,14/0999,,1,,,,,,,,,,2000,80,1.3,,,,0,0,,,
```

So in this style:

- 1st row, after 12th "," is value "5",
- 2nd row skipped, because of 1 on the beginning,
- 3rd row, after 12th "," is value "9",
- 4-6 rows skipped, because of 1 on the beginning,
- 7th row, after 12th "," is value "1"

So sum is 5 + 9 + 1 = 15.

I already input read lines with patch + data taken from label and + extension.

But what next ? How should i handle this ?

```
int count = File.ReadLines(patch + label97.Text + ".ext").Count(line => !line.All(char.IsWhiteSpace));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you should be doing this:

```
File.ReadLines(patch + label97.Text + ".ext")
    .Where(line => !line.StartsWith("1") // get lines that do not start with 1
    .ToArray();
```

Then, using the loop statement of your choice:

```
var desiredPart = line.Split(new[] { ',' })[11]; // get whatever is at the twelveth position
int value = int.Parse(desiredPart);
```

Of course, you need to check that the Split actually gives you 12 positions and whether it's a number or not.

Comment: As i mentioned in a comment, i suggested OP use your approach, but with additional checking of splitted line. I'm on a phone so I cannot give him an example...

Answer (score 0):

You should first perform a string split on the character ',' and save the split string as an array. Then you can access the 0th element to see if it is 0 or 1, and then the 12th element for summing.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume file is in correct format and that on every 12th position you will find whole number, you can do it with just one line (quick and dirty)

```
var sum = File.ReadLines(patch + label97.Text + ".ext")
    .Where(l =>!l.StartsWith("1"))
    .Sum(l => int.Parse(l.Split(',')[11]);
```

bear in mind that this will throw an exception if just one thing is not as expected (wrong filename, wrong position, string on 12th position instead of number etc).

Comment: Doesn't that LinQ (besides being pretty) make it kind of hard to add checks? I don't see how to easily start using int.TryParse or check that it actually has 12 positions without duplicating the split part

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto as i said, this is quick and dirty solution which assumes that everything is in its place. Parsing csv this way is generally bad idea, nevermind the Linq. But, as demonstration, this will do

Comment: I'm aware of that, I just wanted to see if you had any more LinQ tricks :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you could eventually add function in Sum, or iterate through list with `ForEach` and code block, but that code will still be prone to exceptions

Comment: But if i'd like to use this "dirty" version, i have problems, because System.IndexOutOfRangeException in int.Parse(l.Split(',')[11]));
For sure checking has to be done to avoid any errors and problems.

Comment: @Tom in that case, take a look at camilo's approach. in second part, split line by commas, check if legth of array is 12 etc...

Comment: Thanks guys ! Works !